# How do you make git diff use gitx --diff on OS X

Tags: git, macos, diff

Gitx has a great diff viewer, how do I make git automatically pipe git diff *whatever* into gitx?

I've tried to set git config diff.external to a shell script that looks like this:

```
git diff "$2" "$5" | gitx
```

However, that only opens all the individual files up into multiple gitx windows, and it really messes up the files names (changes them all to tmp files with crazy names).

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 18):

like sigjuice is saying up there. Only that noobs (like i am now) need to know how to "connect" git to use it. Here is what I did

```
echo 'opendiff $2 $5' > ~/opendiff-git.sh
chmod a+x ~/opendiff-git.sh
git config --global diff.external ~/opendiff-git.sh
```

and now all "git diff whatever" should open FileMerge.app ...

Comment: opendiff "$2" "$5" -merge "$5"  

Works with paths that have spaces in them. ⌘-s saves changes from FileMerge back to the local file.

Comment: How would I undo this change (if say, I got sick of opendiff and wanted to go back to the inline diff tool)?

Comment: @the Will Cole:
`git config --global --unset diff.external`

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure this is what you want but for us on Macs it sure is handy anyway and somewhat related, you might want to try:

$ git difftool -t opendiff #hash

That opens the diff in the opendiff program which I find very useful. This is much easier than creating a shell script and forcing all your diffs through the new external diff. If you are not on a Mac you can probably change the opendiff into your favorite available diff tool...

Comment: make that “git difftool…” (w/o dash)

Comment: Looks like you can't (-change the opendiff into your favorite available diff tool...), `-t mysupertool` causes *Unknown merge tool 'mysupertool'*

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry this doesn't really answer your question about gitx.  I'm not even sure if gitx can function as a generic diff tool. You might like FileMerge, a merge/diff tool included in the Xcode install.  There is a script called  opendiff that can launch it for you.  Simply make a script with the following line in it and point diff.external at it.

```
opendiff $2 $5
```

Comment: gitx is a great generic diff tool

Answer (score 2):

I did this for Araxis merge, but modifying these basic instructions should not be hard for whatever you perferred tool is.

First I created ~/bin/git-diff-driver.sh and added execute permission to the file.

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/compare -title1:"$1 (repo version)" -title2:"$1 " -max "$2" "$5"
```

Araxis installs it's command line interface tools in /usr/local/bin  The compare tool is their generic tool and the araxis* tools feed through compare.

Once this is set up the following lines need to be added to ~/.gitconfig

```
[merge]
    tool = araxismerge
[mergetool "araxismerge"]
    cmd = "/usr/local/bin/compare -3 -merge -wait $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE $MERGED"
    path = /usr/local/bin/
[diff]
    external = "/Users/mark/bin/git-diff-driver.sh"
```

This redirects all 2-way and 3-way diffs through Araxis Merge.  It seems like the "path =" shouldn't be necessary, but it works.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this script which I have named `git-diffx` and put in my path:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(git diff $@)

if [ "$result" ]; then
   echo "$result" | gitx
fi
```

Then instead of `git diff ...`, you call `git diffx ...`.

Answer (score 2):

This question might be a little old, but I just found something that works for me.

Open GitX app(v.7), select "GitX" menu then "Enable Terminal Usage"

At terminal pipe diff to gitx via:

git diff | gitx

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool) a while back. That answer may help you. There are a couple of questions in there, but one has to do with opening a diff view in something other than FileMerge.