# Unable to understand how Git's difftool configs are set

Tags: git, macos, difftool

I needed to use in my old Git similar settings to the following to be able use difftool. The settings are not exactly the same, since I by accident removed my old .gitconfig.

```
 [merge]
     tool=opendiff

 [mergetool]
     tool=opendiff

 [difftool]
     difftool=opendiff
```

I have an empty .gitconfig at Home.
I can use still the opendiff -tool.
This is a surprise, since it should be impossible.

**How do Git's difftool settings work internally?**

Comment: Just updated my answer about git config files chosen when updating git settings.

Comment: Just updated my answer with value of prefix for Mac OsX

Comment: I have my git external diff tool setup documented in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267761/what-does-your-gitconfig-contain/596821#596821

This may be helpful.  Let me know if you also would like the script that that answer contains as an exercise for the reader.  I did that because it is pretty specific to Araxis Merge.

Comment: @Mark: Please, show me that the script which is specific to Araxis Merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see a [complete setup using mergetool and difftool here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825478/how-to-set-araxis-as-diff-merge-tool-for-msys-git).

If the setting seems to still be active, it may be because it has been set globally or in your account, since there are three files where git-config will search for configuration options:

```
$GIT_DIR/config
```

Repository specific configuration file. (The filename is of course relative to the repository root, not the working directory.)

```
~/.gitconfig
```

User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file at your Git's installation location:

```
$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
```

System-wide configuration file.

---

Git saves the user info wherever you say it to save when you type '`git config`':

From [git config manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> The file-option can be one of `--system`, `--global` or `--file` which specify where the values will be read from or written to.
>   The default is to assume the config file of the current repository, .git/config unless defined otherwise with `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_CONFIG`.
>
> You can override these rules either by command line options or by environment variables. The `--global` and the `--system` options will limit the file used to the global or system-wide file respectively.
>   The `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable has a similar effect, but you can specify any filename you want.

May be you had that environment variable set in your previous installation?

```
GIT_CONFIG
```

Take the configuration from the given file instead of `.git/config`. Using the "`--global`" option forces this to `~/.gitconfig`. Using the "`--system`" option forces this to `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`.

Note: for Mac OsX, `$(prefix)` should be `/usr/local` (if you installed Git as [described here](http://www.killswitchcollective.com/articles/36_git_it_got_it_good))

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
which git
```

Comment: @VonC: How can you change the setting where Git saves the user info?  --- My old Git saved everything to .gitconfig. My current Git saves everything to $GIT_DIR/config.

Comment: @VonC: Where is the folder $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig? I did not find it in my OS/X.

Comment: @Masi, oh, that the default *Unix* directory, but I will check where that translate for a Mac

Comment: Got it: http://www.killswitchcollective.com/articles/36_git_it_got_it_good : /usr/local

Comment: @VonC: Is [---] a comment in Git such that I can use only % tool=opendiff % once in my .gitconfig?

Comment: The new question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081186/is-a-comment-in-git-in-gitconfig

Answer (score 3):

You have also (in addition to remembering about many places Git searches for configuration, as stated in [response by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063618/unable-to-understand-how-gits-difftool-configs-are-set/1063646#1063646)) to remember that both [git-difftool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html) and [git-mergetool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) provide some autodetection / autodiscovery (in some fixed order of preference) of which tools you have available.

This *might* be why "git difftool" invokes opendiff on your computer.

Comment: +1. I tried to check in the script 'git-merge-tool' where that default auto-detection setting might take place, but did not find anything at first glance. Do you know if the auto-detection is scripted, or is within some git executable?

Comment: VonC's question is now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064103/is-gits-auto-detection-scripted-or-is-it-within-some-git-executable

Comment: @VonC: Check 'guess_merge_tool' function in 'git-mergetool--lib' (in "git --exec-dir").