# Is Git's auto-detection scripted or is it within some Git executable?

Tags: git, difftool, mergetool

This question is based on VonC's comment at the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063618/unable-to-understand-how-gits-difftool-configs-are-set/1063889#1063889).

**Is Git's auto-detection for difftool or mergetool scripted or is it within some Git executable?**

Comment: Jakub Narębski just find the right section in the Git script: See my completed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's scripted in git-mergetool. I found this at line 344 of my copy.

```
if test -z "$merge_tool"; then
    merge_tool=`git config merge.tool`
    if test -n "$merge_tool" && ! valid_tool "$merge_tool"; then
        echo >&2 "git config option merge.tool set to unknown tool: $merge_tool"
        echo >&2 "Resetting to default..."
        unset merge_tool
    fi
fi

if test -z "$merge_tool" ; then
    if test -n "$DISPLAY"; then
        merge_tool_candidates="kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld gvimdiff"
        if test -n "$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" ; then
            merge_tool_candidates="meld $merge_tool_candidates"
        fi
        if test "$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = "true"; then
            merge_tool_candidates="kdiff3 $merge_tool_candidates"
        fi
    fi
    if echo "${VISUAL:-$EDITOR}" | grep 'emacs' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        merge_tool_candidates="$merge_tool_candidates emerge"
    fi
(snip)
```

Comment: I need to download a new Git and see its source. My git is in a compiled format such that it is impossible to read it. @ How can you see your Git's source code without downloading a new one?

Comment: @Masi: While git itself is compiled, a lot of the commands (like mergetool) are in fact just scripts tucked away somewhere. On my system these are mostly stored in /usr/lib/git-core/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [git mergetool man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html),

```
--tool=<tool>
```

> Use the merge resolution program specified by .
>   Valid merge tools are: kdiff3, tkdiff, meld, xxdiff, emerge, vimdiff, gvimdiff, ecmerge, diffuse, tortoisemerge, opendiff and araxis.

Now, where does that list comes from?

Actually, those tools (and their custom options) are used in the script:

```
<Git>/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib
```

and used by the script git-mergetool, which does the selection based on `git config merge.tool` command.

But there is a bit of 'auto-selection' based on the valid_tool() function in git-mergetool--lib:

```
valid_tool ()
```

It uses get_merge_tool_cmd() which is based on `mergetool.<aMergeToolName>.cmd`.
If that setting remain in one of the git config files... that tool will be selected.

---

Right..., [**Jakub Narębski**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narbski) just pointed out the right section in the `git-mergetool--lib` script:

```
get_merge_tool () {
    # Check if a merge tool has been configured
    merge_tool=$(get_configured_merge_tool)
    # Try to guess an appropriate merge tool if no tool has been set.
    if test -z "$merge_tool"; then
        merge_tool="$(guess_merge_tool)" || exit
    fi
    echo "$merge_tool"
}
```

That function aptly named **`guess_merge_tool()`** (you think I should be able to find it!...) does amongst other thing, the following, which could explain it detects opendiff:

```
# Loop over each candidate and stop when a valid merge tool is found.
for i in $tools
do
    merge_tool_path="$(translate_merge_tool_path "$i")"
    if type "$merge_tool_path" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$i"
        return 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: Actually it is 'guess_merge_tool' function in 'git-mergetool--lib'

Answer (score 1):

Compare to [my 2009 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064221/6309), the scripts (like [`git-mergetool--lib.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d8370d44547d69e0734e47bb1c38e7ccd3e5387#diff-24efe59feb7bef3b0ab92992dd2d8fdc4ef35ca58e45c1302bb85ffe3fd3bd6a)) have changed With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023):
"[`git mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d8370d44547d69e0734e47bb1c38e7ccd3e5387/Documentation/git-mergetool.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool))</sup> and [`git difftool`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d8370d44547d69e0734e47bb1c38e7ccd3e5387/Documentation/git-difftool.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool))</sup> learns a new configuration `guiDefault` to optionally favor configured guitool over non-gui-tool automatically when `$DISPLAY` is set.

See [commit 42943b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436) (18 Mar 2023) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9d8370d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d8370d44547d69e0734e47bb1c38e7ccd3e5387), 17 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436): new config guiDefault supports auto-toggling gui by DISPLAY
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: David Aguilar</sup>

> When no `merge.tool` or `diff.tool` is configured or manually selected, the selection of a default tool is sensitive to the `DISPLAY` variable; in a GUI session a gui-specific tool will be proposed if found, and otherwise a terminal-based one.
> This "GUI-optimizing" behavior is important because a GUI can make a huge difference to a user's ability to understand and correctly complete a non-trivial conflicting merge.
>
> Some time ago the `merge.guitool` and `diff.guitool` config options were introduced to enable users to configure both a GUI tool, and a non-GUI tool (with fallback if no GUI tool configured), in the same environment.
>
> Unfortunately, the `--gui` argument introduced to support the selection of the guitool is still explicit.
> When using configured tools, there is no equivalent of the no-tool-configured "propose a GUI tool if we are in a GUI environment" behavior.
>
> As proposed in xmqqmtb8jsej.fsf@gitster.g, introduce new configuration options, `difftool.guiDefault` and `mergetool.guiDefault`, supporting a special value "auto" which causes the corresponding tool or guitool to be selected depending on the presence of a non-empty `DISPLAY` value.
> Also support "`true`" to say "default to the guitool (unless `--no-gui` is passed on the commandline)", and "`false`" as the previous default behavior when these new configuration options are not specified.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436/Documentation/config/difftool.txt#L37-L43):

> ### `difftool.guiDefault`
>
> Set `true` to use the `diff.guitool` by default (equivalent to specifying
> the `--gui` argument), or `auto` to select `diff.guitool` or `diff.tool`
> depending on the presence of a `DISPLAY` environment variable value. The
> default is `false`, where the `--gui` argument must be provided
> explicitly for the `diff.guitool` to be used.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436/Documentation/config/mergetool.txt#L88-L94):

> ### `mergetool.guiDefault`
>
> Set `true` to use the `merge.guitool` by default (equivalent to
> specifying the `--gui` argument), or `auto` to select `merge.guitool`
> or `merge.tool` depending on the presence of a `DISPLAY` environment
> variable value. The default is `false`, where the `--gui` argument
> must be provided explicitly for the `merge.guitool` to be used.

`git difftool` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436/Documentation/git-difftool.txt#L100-L105):

> `diff.guitool` variable instead of `diff.tool`. This may be
> selected automatically using the configuration variable
> `difftool.guiDefault`. The `--no-gui` option can be used to
> override these settings. If `diff.guitool` is not set, we will
> fallback in the order of `merge.guitool`, `diff.tool`,
> `merge.tool` until a tool is found.

`git mergetool` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42943b950e12f2d3e56688ecef1b0502e162b436/Documentation/git-mergetool.txt#L92-L94):

> This overrides a previous `-g` or `--gui` setting or
> `mergetool.guiDefault` configuration and reads the default merge
> tool from the configured `merge.tool` variable.

Example:

```bash
git config merge.guitool myguitool
git config mergetool.myguitool.cmd "(printf \"gui \" && cat \"\$REMOTE\") >\"\$MERGED\""
git config mergetool.myguitool.trustExitCode true
```