# Using xxdiff to merge in linux?

Tags: linux, git, merge

I want to use xxdiff for my merging needs. I have just started using git, and I integrated xxdiff to work with it on (git mergetool).

My problem is that I can't find any resource that teaches the basic of merging branches with xxdiff, so I get into this three file window with LOCAL BASE REMOTE, but I don't know where to start to get my merge done.

Could anyone point me to a good resource to learn xxdiff merge basics quickly ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally, you should use `git` to merge branches and a merge tool such as `xdiff` to help resolve merge conflicts in files. From your question, it sounds like you are OK with using `git` but want help with `xdiff`. Can you confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Yes Charles, that would be the case. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, as I don't use xxdiff myself, I'm afraid I can't be much help. Other than point you at the documentation which you probably know about anyway: http://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/xxdiff-doc.html#merging-files-and-resolving-conflicts .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did setup `xxdiff` like I illustrated with [those git settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer/949242#949242) (replace 'difftool' by 'mergetool' in your instance), you have then to compare [those three files](https://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/xxdiff-doc.html#comparing-three-files) and resolve [the differences](https://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/xxdiff-doc.html#merging-files-and-resolving-conflicts).
Note: regarding Git, `xxdiff` is part of the tools [automatically recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064103/is-gits-auto-detection-scripted-or-is-it-within-some-git-executable/1064221#1064221) by the mergetool setting.

I am not sure there is anything `xxdiff`-specific in the resolution of a [three-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge). You can see an illustration of such a merge in term of [versions being compared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771).
The resolution is quite similar to [other diff graphical tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209122208/http://gitguru.com:80/2009/02/22/integrating-git-with-a-visual-merge-tool).
Here  is a [xxdiff resolution tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629043916/http://puma.nerc.ac.uk:80/trac/UM_TUTORIAL/wiki/UmTutorial/ResolvingConflicts) (not *exactly* xxdiff-centric, but still useful).

[image]
<sub>(source: [nerc.ac.uk](https://puma.nerc.ac.uk/trac/UM_TUTORIAL/chrome/site/images/xxdiff.gif))</sub>

Comment: Note that you can also bring up "merged view" if you like such a thing, that shows the results of your selections.