# How do I resolve a conflict after git pull?

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, git-pull

I have to solve some conflict after a `git pull`.

```
$ git pull
CONFLICT (rename/add): Renamed vignette_generator_mashed.h->vision_problem_8.h in 49423dd0d47abe6d839a783b5517bdfd200a202f. vision_problem_8.h added in HEAD
Added as vision_problem_8.h~HEAD_1 instead
Removed vignette_generator_cross_square.cc
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So I googled it a bit, and found people saying using `git mergetool`. But here is what I got:

```
$ git mergetool
merge tool candidates: meld kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld gvimdiff emerge opendiff emerge vimdiff
No files need merging
$ git mergetool opendiff
merge tool candidates: meld kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld gvimdiff emerge opendiff emerge vimdiff
opendiff: file not found
```

So does it mean I have to install something?

What if I simply want the version from `git pull` to overwrite everything?

Comment: For information, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064103/is-gits-auto-detection-scripted-or-is-it-within-some-git-executable (regarding the way Git proposes and search for merge tools)

Comment: And you can see and example of installing/setting a `mergetool` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825478/how-to-set-araxis-as-diff-merge-tool-for-msys-git

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need mergetool for this. It can be resolved pretty easily manually.

Your conflict is that your local commits added a file, `vision_problem_8.h`, that a remote commit also created, by a rename from `vignette_generator_mashed.h`. If you run `ls -l vision_problem_8.h*` you will probably see multiple versions of this file that git has preserved for you. One of them will be yours, another of them will be the remote version. You can use an editor or whatever tools you like to resolve the conflicting contents. When you're done, `git add` the affected files and commit to complete the merge.

If you just want to use the remote commit's version, then you can just move the copy that you didn't write into place and `git add` it.

---

Regarding the merge tools, have a look at `git help mergetool`. Basically, it's going to try running each of the included possibilities until it finds one, or use one you have explicitly configured.

Comment: Thanks! You help me solve the problem. May I still ask what is wrong with my mergetool? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Most likely you don't have your mergetool configured. Use git config --global mergetool.[tool].cmd = [command-line call] You can use many diff tools like kdiff3, tkdiff, xxdiff or many others. See http://gitguru.com/2009/02/22/integrating-git-with-a-visual-merge-tool/

Answer (score 7):

I think you just forgot the `-t` switch at your command line. According to Git's help page, it stands for `-t <tool>, --tool=<tool>`, so it makes what you intended to.

Try:

```bash
git mergetool -t gvimdiff
```

Of course you may use your prefered merge tool instead of mine, `gvimdiff`. Meld is great too...

Comment: This would be a better answer if there was some explanation of what the switch `-t` actually does, and *why* it solves the problem.

Comment: @Stewart Done. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 5):

If you run your merge from a subdirectory of your project, git will run the merge for your whole project. However, mergetool can only see (and merge) files in or below the working directory. So, if this scenario occurs, make sure you are trying to run your conflict resolution from the top-level directory in your project.

Answer (score 5):

*What if I simply want the version from git pull to overwrite everything?*
If you want just that you should use:

```
 git fetch
 git reset --hard origin/your-branch-name
```

Comment: yee it should be hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper branching strategy (i.e. features are merged into develop, just before merging or rebasing etc.), most often when you want to run a  `git pull` on a branch. You basically want to get all the new stuff from the Git server and later on apply your own stuff, which in Git lingua franca is something like this:

```bash
# put all my changes on the stash 
git stash 

# fully reset the current branch to the state it is on the server
git clean -d -x -f ; git reset HEAD --hard ; git pull --force

# apply your own changes 
git stash pop
```

Instead of stashing, you could also put your current state into a temporary branch, but if there are conflicts you would have to manually resolve them eventually.