# Trouble with cloning Octopress blog on other laptops/computers. (conflict isseue when git pull origin master)

Tags: git, github, clone, blogs, octopress

I'm a beginner to Git, and I have trouble with cloning Octopress blog. (My primary laptop accidentally crashed...so I tried to get my blog back from other laptops by pulling my Octopress from GitHub) so I tried as following this 
http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/ 
but I got error message on terminal when I tried the last step as this:

```
$ cd ./_deploy
$ git pull origin master  # update the local master branch
```

I got this error:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 518, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (386/386), done.
remote: Total 518 (delta 221), reused 350 (delta 59)
Receiving objects: 100% (518/518), 256.54 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (221/221), done.
From github.com:yhagio/yhagio.github.com
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging index.html
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in index.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, please teach me how to fix this.
I am beginner, so I really don't know.

And, When I "git status" I got this :

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   README.md
#   new file:   about/index.html
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/background.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/blankButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/divider.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/fullscreenButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/fullscreenButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/muteButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/muteButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/normalscreenButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/normalscreenButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/pauseButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/pauseButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/playButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/playButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/timeSliderBuffer.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/timeSliderCapLeft.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/timeSliderCapRight.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/timeSliderProgress.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/timeSliderRail.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/unmuteButton.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/unmuteButtonOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/display/background.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/display/bufferIcon.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/display/muteIcon.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/display/playIcon.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/dock/button.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/glow.xml
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/item.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/itemOver.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/sliderCapBottom.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/sliderCapTop.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/sliderRail.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/playlist/sliderThumb.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/sharing/embedIcon.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/sharing/embedScreen.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/sharing/shareIcon.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/glow/sharing/shareScreen.png
#   new file:   assets/jwplayer/player.swf
#   new file:   atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/05/hello/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/05/how-to-install-rails-on-ubuntu-12-dot-10/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/05/web-development-related-books/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/06/news-letters-for-web-developers/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/06/notes-deployment-options-and-tech-overview/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/06/ruby-and-rails-learning-resources/index.html
#   new file:   blog/2013/04/06/stuffs-for-sublime-text/index.html
#   new file:   blog/archives/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/learn/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/learn/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/notes/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/notes/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/rails/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/rails/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/ruby/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/ruby/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/test/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/test/index.html
#   new file:   blog/categories/ubuntu/atom.xml
#   new file:   blog/categories/ubuntu/index.html
#   new file:   favicon.png
#   new file:   images/bird_32_gray.png
#   new file:   images/bird_32_gray_fail.png
#   new file:   images/code_bg.png
#   new file:   images/dotted-border.png
#   new file:   images/email.png
#   new file:   images/line-tile.png
#   new file:   images/noise.png
#   new file:   images/rss.png
#   new file:   images/search.png
#   new file:   javascripts/github.js
#   new file:   javascripts/libs/jXHR.js
#   new file:   javascripts/libs/jquery.min.js
#   new file:   javascripts/libs/swfobject-dynamic.js
#   new file:   javascripts/modernizr-2.0.js
#   new file:   javascripts/octopress.js
#   new file:   javascripts/pinboard.js
#   new file:   javascripts/twitter.js
#   new file:   robots.txt
#   new file:   sitemap.xml
#   new file:   stylesheets/screen.css
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both added:         index.html
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   index.html.BACKUP.10518.html
#   index.html.BACKUP.10568.html
#   index.html.BACKUP.10632.html
#   index.html.BACKUP.9048.html
#   index.html.BACKUP.9560.html
#   index.html.BACKUP.9753.html
#   index.html.BASE.10518.html
#   index.html.BASE.10568.html
#   index.html.BASE.10632.html
#   index.html.BASE.9048.html
#   index.html.BASE.9560.html
#   index.html.BASE.9753.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.10518.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.10568.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.10632.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.9048.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.9560.html
#   index.html.LOCAL.9753.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.10518.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.10568.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.10632.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.9048.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.9560.html
#   index.html.REMOTE.9753.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, it's Git telling you that there's a conflict on a file that it was trying to pull of the remote repository.

So open `index.html`, [resolve the conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435754/how-do-i-resolve-a-conflict-after-git-pull), `git add` it and then `commit`.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see any “<<<<<<<”, “>>>>>>>” and “=======” markers in index.html. Do I have to install some mergetools ?

Comment: No. Right after you get the `CONFLICT` message, what out put do you get if you do `git status`?

Comment: I edited the question, I got bunch of file names when I did "git status"

Comment: By lookin at your `git status` output, it's clear that `index.html` has conflicts. Can you please open it and paste it's code on pastie.org or something?

Comment: Can you then git `add` & `commit`? The pull should be finished then.

Comment: Agis! Thank you, I found a  “<<<<<<<”, “>>>>>>>” and “=======” markers in _config.yml and I erased it, it did work! :) I am so happy! Thank you very much for helping me!