# Git pull, what happens in real life?

Tags: xcode, git

Ok I’m new to this. 
If there is a remote repo and I have cloned it on my mac, when I git pull and someone else has made changes to the master will my changes be overwritten?

What rules followed?
In my current experience files that I have not modified are overwritten but I don’t have any experience as to what would happen if files that I have modified and someone else modified have conflicts. Will I be asked to make a decision or will it be overwritten?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of pull conflict, you will have chance to choose whether you lose your own change or not. Here shows how to resolve it ([How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)). But of course you must communicate with the team on this.

It's always best to avoid such conflict. Using `branches` helps, when working within a group. Here is a great insight: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I don’t get it. From my experience I’m never asked to choose. My files are updated automatically. What if I didn’t want to accept changes from the master?

Comment: If you don't want changes from master, why did you pull in the first place?

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Here mentions about `mergetool` you may want to setup.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435754/how-do-i-resolve-a-conflict-after-git-pull Note that `git pull` is `git fetch` plus `git merge`.

Comment: Because I do not know if I want them yet or not. I have to see first. Also it’s good to have a choice.

Comment: @GeorgeAsda then what you need is `git fetch`. By `git fetch` you can get commits from others down to your repo, without merging them to your branch. You can check these commits and decide if you are going to merge them. And you can choose which of these commits, some or all, to "merge" into your branch, through `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`.

Comment: Thank you ElpieKay!

Answer (score 0):

> If there is a remote repo and I have cloned it on my mac, when I git
>   pull and someone else has made changes to the master will my changes
>   be overwritten?

Yes the changes will be added(integerated) on to the local copy of your current branch, if you do the git pull.

What git pull does, you might find plenty of info about that? 
To keep it short.  This add or incorporate the changes from remote repo to your current branch.

```
git pull = git fetch + git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

---

> What rules followed? In my current experience files that I have not
>   modified are overwritten but I don’t have any experience as to what
>   would happen if files that I have modified and someone else modified
>   have conflicts. Will I be asked to make a decision or will it be
>   overwritten?

Answer to the second question. Your current branch is not up to date with `origin/master` when you do the git pull, it will fetch and add all the changes. If you see if there is conflict between the files, you can solve that using several GUI tools. example, `vimdiff`, `kdiff3`, `meld`, `diffuse`, and so on you can configure that in your mergetool config.

[How to resolve git merge conflicts in cli?](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/)