# Is [---] a comment in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, comments

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063618/unable-to-understand-how-gits-difftool-configs-are-set/1063646).

Is `[---]` a comment in Git such that I can use only `% tool=opendiff %` once in my `.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are asking whether the square bracket syntax in `.gitconfig` means something significant. The answer is yes, it separates `.gitconfig` into sections. Each section has a name, shown between the square brackets. For example:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
```

In the above example, the section name is `core`. If you change the word `core` to something else, Git won't be able to find, for example, the `bare` option because it needs to be inside the `core` section.

The [git-config(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config) manual page has a whole section describing the format of the configuration file.

Comment: # and ; begins comments in .gitconfig, while you can have also subsections in [core "subSection"] in .gitconfig. Those are the keypoints which I found from the manual. --- Thank you for your answer!

Comment: To be precise, a `#` **or** `;` character indicates a comment, not `#` _and_ `;`.