# How can I setup my .git/config to be able to push to / pull from multiple remote repositories?

Tags: git, heroku, unfuddle, multiple-repositories

Ok, I have three different computers that I work from and right now their configurations are all different so I have to push/pull a certain on each and its very bothersome. What I want to do is have ONE config file that I can use for all three that will allow me to do the following:

```
git push unfuddle
git pull heroku
git push unfuddle
git pull heroku
```

And I'm new to git, so I know that maybe I need `heroku master` or 'heroku origin` or somethign?

Here is what my config file looks like right now:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@heroku.com:HEROKU-APP.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "unfuddle"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@UNFUDDLE-APP.unfuddle.com:UNFUDDLE-APP/UNFUDDLE-APP.git
```

Obviously the git urls were changed to protect the innocent. What should I change so that I can easily push and pull to/from both of these repos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there are **[three levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063618/unable-to-understand-how-gits-difftool-configs-are-set/1063646#1063646)** of [config files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

- config local to your current repo
- config local to your current user (home directory)
- config local to your system

You can define as many remote repo addresses you want, and you can do it at the user level, provided you synchronize that config file from destop to destop

```
git remote add origin1 git+ssh://remote.location/git/repository1.git
git remote add origin2 git+ssh://remote.location/git/repository2.git
git remote add origin3 git+ssh://remote.location/git/repository3.git
```

If those commands add the remote addresses only in your current *repo* config file, you can manually move those to your current *user* config file.

But on each repo, you need to define your [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch) for the right repo:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin1/master
```

(from Git1.7.0, quicker than the two `git config branch` you had to do before)

So if you have the right synchronization mechanism (like [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for instance) for your user config file, you are all set.