# GIT diff GUI

Tags: git, version-control, diff

I have a rather large diff of 2 GIT branches and would like to open them in some sort of nice UI side by side.
Something that shows me the diff's easily, and hopefully that I can merge differences
one by one.
git diff is rather hard to work with.

Comment: I'm going to add this as a comment since I've never used it but does [gitk][1] do the trick?  


  [1]: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html

Comment: whoops...sorry about that.  thought comments were formatted too.

Comment: Jarub Nareski just gave me the answer...git difftool is the key....very kool, you can use opendiff for example to quickly merge 2 broken branches into 1 unbroken one. My problem is everything except 1 thing works on one branch, the other one has that exact thing working, and I would have spent 10 hours until I found out I mispelled a word, took me 3 minutes with opendiff

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825478/how-to-set-araxis-as-diff-merge-tool-for-msys-git/1017034#1017034 for a practical example of git difftool setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is [git difftool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html) (at least for git version 1.6.3 and later). Please remember that it just invokes configured or automatically found graphical diff tool.

Comment: Example: git difftool --tool=opendiff testbranch master

Comment: Instead of "testbranch master", which will show diffs between testbranch and master, when reviewing branch "testbranch" you often want to see only the commits on that branch. Use "master...testbranch" for this (three periods.) If testbranch is the current HEAD, then this can be abbreviated to "master..."

Comment: @JonathanHartley: Diff is always about two endpoints, not about range of commits.  In graphical repository browser such as e.g. `gitk` (or `git log --graph`) the `master...testbranch` shows both branches to common ancestor.  For diff `master...testbranch` is a shortcut for diff of common ancestor and (I think) `testbranch`.

Comment: @viper33m: Any details would be appreciated.  Could you please post a bug report on git@vger.kernel.org ?

Comment: @JakubNarębski I'm sorry, it seems that just meld doesn't work in ubuntus older that 10.10, not the actual difftool. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meld/+bug/579487

Answer (score 25):

I use [`kompare`](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/):

```
git diff | kompare -
```

`kompare` is not limited to git, you may also do

```
svn diff | kompare -
bzr diff | kompare -
diff -Naur clean/ patched/ | kompare -
kompare bug3.fix.diff
```

... you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. Works with `meld` also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the process of merging, `git diff` has a really nice syntax where the first two columns show the parentage of each line, in a kind of unified merge diff. From there it's easy to resolve the conflicts with any editor.

Do you have the pretty colors turned on? Here's a snippet from my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[color]
    diff = auto
    branch = auto
    status = auto
    interactive = auto
```

Anyway, take a look at kdiff3, for instance. You can specify the tool to be used for merging, see the [git-mergetool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) docs for details.