# git diff - external viewer - get all diff results

Tags: git, shell, diff

When external diff is configured, results are displayed per file, i.e. to view differences for the next file one needs to close currently running diff viewer.

Is there a way to make git spawn all diff viewer processes in parallel?

If I just spawn process from within external diff script, apparently git deletes the temporary files it uses for comparison.

So

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen(('/usr/bin/meld', sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]))
#p.wait()
```

does not work, with meld displaying 'Could not read from '/tmp/.diff_VlLwKF'

However, if I uncomment

```
#p.wait()
```

everything works fine, but again, it's sequential spawning, not parallel.

Thanks

Comment: What environment are you using? It should be possible to write a wrapper than spawns a viewer in the background and use this as your difftool.

Comment: Please see question, added some more info

Comment: I think you can configure git to not delete temporary files it uses for comparison (see git-config/git-difftool manpage).

Comment: How is the external diff configured? I simply set the PAGER environment variable to my external program and I get the complete diff file in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked a similar question on SO, wanting to open diff files in tabs in BeyondCompare. I came up with this:

```
for name in $(git diff --name-only $1); do git difftool $1 $name & done
```

This gets the list of modified files and calls the external diff tool in a background task on each separate file.

Check out the [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial/1291578#1291578) and how I make it easy to use. Being new to bash I'd love to hear of any improvements...

Edit 1: added optional param (eg '--staged')
Edit 2: added git alias ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial/1291578#1291578)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the difftool for each files, you could let git do that for you, starting with ([git 1.7.11](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1307164), June 2012):
It can now diff directories (ie display all the files to be compared, before opening the difftool)

See "[`git difftool` to give directory compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115188/6309)"

So maybe you can now use one call, with directory diff.