# Using git difftool to view differences in entire directory

Tags: git, diff, difftool, opendiff

I'm having trouble trying to use git difftool (in this case, opendiff for mac) to visualise the differences made in the latest git commit. I don't want to launch opendiff for each pair of files that has changed, I just want to launch one instance of opendiff which compares the entire directory, so I've followed the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113889/git-difftool-to-give-directory-compare) which is to use `--dir-diff`. I ended up using this command:

```
git difftool HEAD^ HEAD --dir-diff
```

The problem is that when I launch this command, the opendiff says that there are 0 differences (even though using normal diff will show differences in multiple files). What's going on? How do I use difftool correctly?

Comment: That answer specifies that the diff tool must be able to "compare two directory hierarchies at a time after populating two temporary directories". Can `opendiff` do that?

Comment: The command you provided works well for me with `meld` on Linux. Maybe `opendiff` issue?

Comment: Perhaps `git log -p -1` would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

The files get deleted immediately because opendiff (the command line tool) exits straight after launching FileMerge (the GUI tool). You need to write a short wrapper script that will copy the left and right folders to (another) temp location and start opendiff with those locations.

Edit: you can configure a custom difftool that will start FileMerge directly and wait for it to exit. Add this to your ~/.gitconfig

```
[difftool "fm"]
cmd = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge -left \"$LOCAL\" -right \"$REMOTE\"
path =
```