# Maven. Get result of execution some shell comand

Tags: git, maven-3, execution

I would like to get result of execution some shell command (git rev-list HEAD --count) like a content of tag. Something like this:

`<git-count>git rev-list HEAD --count</git-count>`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You know that `git rev-list HEAD --count` doesn't unambiguously identify a commit? Regardless of whether this is important I suggest you consider `git describe`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a single Git command to get the current tag, branch and commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863756/is-there-a-single-git-command-to-get-the-current-tag-branch-and-commit)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a shell script, run git count in that script and pass the resulting variable to maven, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT_COUNT=$( git rev-list HEAD --count )

mvn install "-Dgit-count=${GIT_COUNT}"
```