# How to launch a Bash function using Git alias

Tags: git, alias, built-in, git-checkout, bash-function

I want to use a Git alias in ~/.gitconfig so that it calls a bash function, if it is defined, otherwise call the regular `git checkout`.

This is what I have devised:

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
...
[alias]
...
    co = !(compgen -A function vxzExecuteGitCheckout >/dev/null && vxzExecuteGitCheckout ) || git checkout
```

The problem is that Git uses /bin/sh (which happens to be `dash` in my case) and it barfs on `compgen` since it is a `bash` builtin.

Any way making sure that Git uses `bash` to execute this command?

Note that `vxzExecuteGitCheckout()` is defined in a file which is not included in ~/.bashrc, yet.

Another question is, if I were to use `git co -b param1 param2 ...`, would the above alias definition pass on the `-b param1 param2` to `git checkout` if this Bash function is not found?

Answer (score 4):

use `bash` explicitely:

```
co = !bash -c '( compgen -A function vxzExecuteGitCheckout >/dev/null && vxzExecuteGitCheckout ) || git checkout' -
```

another possibility would be to write a shell script with the correct shebang line `#!/bin/bash` and call that script for `alias.co` (see the question [How to embed bash script directly inside a git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309430/112968))

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Used this: <br>

`co = !bash -c '(compgen -A function vxzExecuteGitCheckout >/dev/null && vxzExecuteGitCheckout "$@" ) || git checkout "$@"' -`


You might want to explain the importance of trailing dash, because without it the `git co` command seemed to do nothing at all.

Comment: I finally ditched this approach because I wanted the called function vxz... to change the environment variables of the shell I am working in. But since this function gets called in new shell of its own, the environment variable changes do not affect the calling shell.

Comment: @gurjeet: any chance we might know the problem you're trying to solve? maybe there's another way around it

Comment: I work with PostgreSQL sources quite a lot and have a few bash functions that let me do common things. I want these functions to do the right thing everytime I switch to different a Git branch of Postgres sources. To do the right thing, these functions depend on some env. variables, and I want to update these env vars with every checkout. I finally ended up adding a function call to bash special variable $PROMPT_COMMAND. PROMPT_COMMAND=vxzDetectBranchChange. And now everytime I change to a new branch, this function updates all relevant environment variables, including $PATH.

Comment: does anyone know what the trailing dash is for, beacuase without it, it doesn't work?

Comment: @Steve: from [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): »If there are arguments after the command_string, the  first  argument  is  assigned  to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.«