# How to use a bash function in a git alias?

Tags: git, bash, function, config, alias

I want to use a bash function in a git alias. So I added this to my `.bashrc`:

```
fn() {
    echo "Hello, world!"
}
export -f fn
```

and to my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    fn = !fn
```

But then `git fn` produces an error:

```
fatal: cannot run fn: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'fn': 'fn': No such file or directory
```

Is this a correct way to use a bash function in a git alias definition?

Comment: I’d assume that when Git runs a bash command, it does so in its own process which will very likely skip your `.bashrc`. So you would have to define the function inside of the `.gitconfig`, within that alias line. – Alternatively, you could create a `git-fn` file and put it in the PATH and then `git fn` should also work (at least iirc)

Comment: @poke, the point of `export -f` is that the definition is in the environment, so the shell invoked by git doesn't *have* to source `.bashrc` -- if it's actually bash. If it's `/bin/sh`, then it's a question of which implementation one has on hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interesting, I did not know you could put functions into the environment, that’s cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Thats because git uses `/bin/sh` (so your `.bashrc` is not sourced).

You can call bash in a git alias as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483579/7906071).

The thing is the bash shell started by the git command is not loading your `.profile` (which is the one responsible for including the `.bashrc`).

There may be other ways to do it but you can work around by doing:

```
[alias]
    fn = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.my_functions && fn'
```

With the file `.my_functions` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
fn() {
    echo "Hello, world!"
}
```

You can even source `.my_functions` into your `.bashrc` if you want the functions to be available from regular shells.

Comment: There's no need for the `export -f` if you're `source`ing the file. The only value to that is if you're running it in the user's dotfiles and then trying to access the previously-exported function from a subprocess.

Comment: This mostly works. To pass all arguments from the shell into `fn`, you need a ` - ` at the end:
`fn = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.my_functions && fn' - `

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but if I just put a space before the function name in `.gitconfig`, it works without a problem and outputs the message:

```
[alias]
    fn = ! fn
```

It might be a bug in git, or I'm missing something in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be 100% certain that exported functions will be honored, ensure that the shell being called is bash, not `/bin/sh` (which will not honor them if it's implemented by ash or dash).

```
fn() { echo "hello, world"; }
export -f fn
git config --global alias.fn $'!bash -c \'fn "$@"\' _'
git fn
```

...properly emits:

```
hello, world
```

The relevant entry in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    fn = !bash -c 'fn \"$@\"'
```

Comment: To properly pass the arguments, you need to provide a dummy argument that will become $0: `git config --global alias.fn $'!bash -c \'fn "$@"\' x'`

Comment: For me, exporting the function didn't work. I had to add it to ~/.bashrc and use `$'bash -ic \'...`

Comment: @glennjackman, good point about the need for a dummy arg for `$0`. That said, re: exporting not working, can you give me a reproducer for that? (The above code works for me when copied-and-pasted exactly as-is into a session which previously had no `fn` defined).

Comment: (that said, I could definitely see it failing if you had two different bash versions, and one had a vendor or intermediate upstream patch for shellshock and the other had the final upstream patch; environment representations of exported functions haven't been constant for the lifetime of the shell).