# How to make bash as default shell in git alias?

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-alias

Is there a way to specify the default shell used by git alias (which is currently `/bin/sh` for linux systems and `/bin/zsh` for macOS)? I know that we can wrap the command with `bash -c '<command script>'` but I was looking for a way to change the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [hardwired](https://github.com/git/git/search?p=1&q=SHELL_PATH) into the binary.

You can recompile with a different value:

```
./configure --with-shell=PATH
```

but see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46698535