# How to pass parameters from a git alias to an external script

Tags: bash, git, git-alias

I am having a problem passing parameters to an external bash script file from git aliases.  Currently, I have my bash script file in the same directory as my .gitconfig.  I plan on moving all my *complex* `!f() { }` aliases in there to avoid battling all the escaping and no commenting.

So my script file is named .gitconfig.kat.aliases.script and it looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

openInBrowser() {
    REPO_URL=$(git config remote.origin.url)

    find="git@bitbucket.org:"
    replace="https://bitbucket.org/"

    # Replace SSH with HTTPS prefix
    REPO_URL=$(echo $REPO_URL | sed -e "s%${find}%${replace}%g")
    explorer $REPO_URL

    exit 0;
}

checkoutRemoteBranch() {
    echo "$# Parameters"
    echo $0
    echo $1
    echo $2
    if [ "$#" = 2 ] 
    then
        echo -e "BINGO"
        # git fetch
        # git co -b $2 $1/$2
    else
        echo -e "usage:\tgit co-rb <origin> <branch>"
    fi  
}
```

**Configuration 1**

Inside my .gitconfig [alias] section, I have this:

```
co-rb = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && checkoutRemoteBranch \"$@\"'
open = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && openInBrowser'
```

I followed [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46435987/166231) syntax for aliases to an external script/function.  Then, I followed [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435606/how-to-use-a-bash-function-in-a-git-alias#comment79829519_46435837) syntax for passing parameters to the function (above alias isn't passing dummy parameter like the question suggested, more info below).

The problem is, without a dummy parameter, when I execute `git co-rb origin feature/test`, I get the following output:

```
1 Parameters
origin
feature/test
```

**Configuration 2**

If I define a dummy parameter after the $@...

`co-rb = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && checkoutRemoteBranch \"$@\" x'`

The output is:

```
2 Parameters
origin
feature/test
x
```

**Configuration 3**

If I change the position of the dummy parameter to `co-rb = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && checkoutRemoteBranch x \"$@\"'`

The output is:

```
2 Parameters
origin
x
feature/test
```

Issues:
1. Configuration 1 - The parameter count is wrong, and the positional parameters are offset by -1.
1. Configuration 2 - The parameter count is right, but the positional parameters are offset by -1.
1. Configuration 3 - The parameter count is right, but the parameters are all messed up.  `x` is injected in the middle and the positions aren't correct for $1.

How should I set up my git alias so that the parameter count is correct and positions 1..N are what I expect?  Or should I change my shell script so that any time I check parameter count, I check against 'count-1'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ bash -c 'echo $@' 1 2 3
2 3

$ bash -c 'echo $0 $@' 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

That is, `"$@"` passes parameters started from the 1st but in this
situation there is also 0th parameter.

So pass `$0`:

```
co-rb = !bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && checkoutRemoteBranch "$0" "$@"'
```

`$0` is not added to `$@` because in 99 use cases out of 100 it's not needed. Usually it's the shell name or the script name, neither one is needed in `$@`.

Comment: What if one of the parameters I'm trying to forward is a path?  I seem to be getting one parameter for each folder in the path.  Is there a way to package those up into one parameter?  `git myalias 5 "Path/To/File.txt" delete` I'd like to see three parameters for this and not 5.

Comment: The path must be a single parameter: `$ bash -c 'for param in $0 "$@"; do echo "$param"; done' 1 /etc/passwd 3` => output 3 lines:
1
/etc/passwd
3

Comment: I recieved `bash -c 'source $HOME/.gitconfig.kat.aliases.script && undoFile for param in $0 $@: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`