# How to use bash commands on .gitconfig aliases

Tags: git, bash, git-config

I use the command `git ls-tree -r $(git branch | awk '{ print $2 }') --name-only` to show the files on my branch, but i tried to put this command on my `.gitconfig` file as an alias and i got this error:

```
  $ git list
fatal: Not a valid object name $(git
```

My .gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
list = ls-tree -r $(git branch | awk '{ print $2 }') --name-only
```

Thanks
P.D. Sorry for my english

Comment: "If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed bash script directly inside a git alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309430/how-to-embed-bash-script-directly-inside-a-git-alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments, you need to prefix your alias with an exclamation (`!`) mark.

The following entry works for me

```
[alias]
    list = !git ls-tree -r $(git branch | awk '{ print $2 }') --name-only
```

***EDIT***

Alternatively, taking help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6719718/1860929), you can create a file `git-list` in any place in your `PATH`, like below:

#### git-list

```
git ls-tree -r $(git branch | awk '{ print $2 }') --name-only
```

then change its permission to executable using `chmod +x git-list` and you can have your `git list` command working in any directory.

Comment: Answering this makes it harder to close.  It's duplicate, and the core logic is bad.

Comment: @AndrewC Oh, I didn't realise this was a duplicate - there were no existing close votes or comments of that nature.

Comment: I got distracted between commenting and voting to close :)