# How to embed bash script directly inside a Mercurial alias

Tags: bash, mercurial, alias

I have a Mercurial alias that pushes a specified branch to the central repo:

```
[alias]
pushbranch = push -b
```

This works ok, but 90% of the time I want to push the current branch, which I currently do like so:

```
$ hg pushbranch `hg branch`
```

I though I might be able to just update the alias in my `.hgrc` like so:

```
[alias]
pushbranch = push -b `hg branch`
```

But this fails with:

```
pushing to branch`
abort: unknown branch '`hg'!
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309430/how-to-embed-bash-script-directly-inside-a-git-alias) for doing essentially this with Git, but the mechanism used there also does not work with Mercurial, I did:

```
[alias]
pushbranch = push -b '!sh hg branch'
```

and got:

```
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myteam/reponame
abort: unknown branch '!hg branch'!
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mercurial, the alias must start with an exclamation mark to call out to the shell. Within such an alias, `$HG` is available to invoke Mercurial. E.g.:

```
[alias]
pushbranch = !$HG push -b `$HG branch`
```