# How to use a parenthesis character inside a command substitution inside a bash snippet inside a git configuration alias?

Tags: git, bash

Here is an excerpt from the config I am editing. This is inside the `[alias]` section of my `.gitconfig`:

```
ignored = !git ls-files -v | grep "^S"
status-with-ignored = "!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed -e s/^/z/ -e s/$/z/); [ -n \"$ignored\" ] && echo \"git skip-worktree (ignored):\n$ignored\"; };f"
```

I am basically trying to colorize the output of `git ignored` as I stick it onto the end of the git status. What I show above works fine, but it does not work (`fatal: bad config file line 18 in ~/.gitconfig`) if my `sed` command has inside it any parentheses (which are quite useful for building regexes).

For example, I want to be able to write something having parens, such as `sed s/^(.*)$/z\1z/` instead of `sed -e s/^/z/ -e s/$/z/`.

Since i'm colorizing stuff I would actually be using `\x1b[31m`, `\x1b[m`, etc., but you get the idea.

I have tried one, two, three, and four backslashes to escape these parens but nothing works.

Comment: The example is bad since you can write: `sed s/.*/z\0z/`

Comment: BTW i know I can work around this in a large number of other ways (`echo` comes to mind) but the real question is, does there exist a way to make it let me use parens

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for reminding me that `\0` works to fetch the full match but that is just another of the other workarounds

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but I don't see the problem. Let's say you have `sed  's/foo\(.*\)/\1/' <<< 'foobar'` , the you can simply use `echo "$(sed  's/foo\(.*\)/\1/' <<< 'foobar')"`

Comment: For example now I want to use the `<(file)` redirector but git is complaining there is a parse error in the config now.

Comment: @hek2mgl that's exactly it, no amount of backslash escaping of those parens will get git to stop complaining about not being able to parse.

Comment: This works too: `echo $(sed 's/foo\(.*\)/\1/' <(echo 'foobar'))`. I guess the problem is that you need to double escape some characters since the string will be parsed twice: Once by git when reading it from config file and secondly by bash when executing it as a command. Meaning you need \\ instead of \ . But I'm not 100% sure what you are doing, where do you want to place that commands? .bashrc? .git/config?

Comment: `.gitconfig` (similar to `.git/config`)

Comment: I see the issue (have tried it). Let me check that and come back to you later if it has not answered before.

Comment: For my actual application I was able to finagle something together using pipes. I had wanted to use shell input redirection `<()` but that has parens, so I opted for pipes instead

Comment: The same for me.. I didn't had so much time today but using pipes was also the only thing that worked for me. I also couldn't make something like this `<(echo foo)` working.. I can't say why atm. Good question! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are separate problems here: One with your config escaping, one with parentheses in `sed`, and one with process substitution like `<(date)` in git aliases.

#### Config escaping

Firstly, the problem with `bad config file` isn't command substitution, it's your newline character.

```
[YOURS] status-with-ignored = "!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed -e s/^/z/ -e s/$/z/); [ -n \"$ignored\" ] && echo \"git skip-worktree (ignored):\n$ignored\"; };f"
 [MINE] status-with-ignored = "!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed -e s/^/z/ -e s/$/z/); [ -n \"$ignored\" ] && echo \"git skip-worktree (ignored):\\n$ignored\"; };f"
```

It looks like your `\n` is being interpreted as applying to the config file; that's the part that needs escaping, not anything paren-related.

I got the above by letting `bash` and `git config` handle the escaping for me, and then substituting cut's `" "` for `' '`:

```
git config alias.status-with-ignored '!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d " " -f 2 | sed -e s/^/z/ -e s/$/z/); [ -n "$ignored" ] && echo "git skip-worktree (ignored):\n$ignored"; };f'
```

(If you want to get clever about [escaping single quotes within `bash` single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/1426891), you can, but to me it works actively against readability.)

#### Parentheses in sed

Secondly, Bash and other shells can't handle unquoted parentheses. That's not specific to git aliases, that's just the parsing rules.

```
echo I am (Batman)    # Doesn't work
echo I am Batman      # Does work
```

The latter one works; Batman has no parens.

You can either escape the parentheses or quote the string:

```
echo "I am (Batman)"  # Works
echo I am \(Batman\)  # Also works
```

Which leaves your config file like this:

```
status-with-ignored = "!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed -e \"s/^(.*)$/z\1z/\"); [ -n \"$ignored\" ] && echo \"git skip-worktree (ignored):\\n$ignored\"; };f"
```

Or your `git config` statement like this:

```
git config alias.status-with-ignored '!f() { git status; ignored=$(git ignored | cut -d " " -f 2 | sed -e "s/^(.*)$/z\1z/"); [ -n "$ignored" ] && echo "git skip-worktree (ignored):\n$ignored"; };
```

#### Process substitution in git

Finally, it seems that `git alias` just doesn't handle process substitution. From [the `git config` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> Arguments are split by spaces, the usual shell quoting and escaping is supported. A quote pair or a backslash can be used to quote them.

It looks like git is using `sh` or its own parsing, and not calling out to `bash` itself, so as a [non-portable bash extension](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution#Portability) process substitution isn't supported natively. You could shell out to bash:

```
git config alias.sample '!cat <(seq 3)'; git sample
git config alias.sample '!bash -c "cat <(seq 3)"'; git sample
```

...but at that point you might as well just [make a script named `git-status-with-ignored` and add it to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309430/how-to-embed-bash-script-directly-inside-a-git-alias).

Comment: this is very confusing because i am 100% sure the newline has nothing to do with the problem. In fact I try a lot of variations of the version you suggest with the single quotes on the outside and I always get back `fatal: Bad alias.status-with-ignored string: unclosed quote`

Comment: Oh I see now u are saying to call `git config alias` to do the escapement for me.. Ok but the newline is not the issue because I can take it out and the same behavior happens

Comment: @Steven: Oh, I see what's going on: If you want parentheses in a sed argument or anywhere else, you need to quote the argument, which is just an artifact of Bash tokenization. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: thanks, you went over many methods to deal with the various issues and its now totally clear how to bring full bash capability to git aliases. Sweet.