# How to automatically rename tags using git hooks?

Tags: git, githooks, git-tag

I want all the tags created by user to be verified (and renamed if necessary) to satisfy our rules.
For example, if the user has created `"v1.2.3"` tag, it should be automatically renamed to `"v1.02.03"`.

Unfortunately, there is no git hook exists which is being invoked by `git tag` command.

That's why I have implemented `pre-push` hook, which deletes old tag and creates new one (with modified name) on the same commit.

The problem is that `git push --tags` sends OLD TAGS to remote repo instead of NEW TAGS (despite that the old tags do not exist anymore after the pre-push hook has deleted them).

How to rename tags automatically on local repo before pushing them to remote repo?

---

**EDIT :**
I solved my problem by duplicating tag-renaming-logic to `post-receive` hook on server side.
As for now, tag "v1.2.3" gets renamed to "v1.02.03" on client side by `pre-push` hook, but old tag name ("v1.2.3") is being pushed to remote repo, and on remote repo "v1.2.3" gets renamed to "v1.02.03" again by `post-receive` hook.  Now both client and server have the tag renamed.

Should I say that I'm unhappy with my solution?
Pure-client-side solution is still welcome.

Comment: This seems to me a case where the tags were not properly deleted. Could you share the code for pre-push hook here?

Comment: @mu - tags were properly deleted, I see the message about successful operation printed by the hook. My code contains the following line: `os.execute('git tag -d "'..tagname..'" && git tag "'..new_tag_name..'" '..commit..' && echo TAG RENAMED || echo FAILED TO RENAME TAG')`.  And I see them actually deleted after `git push --tags` completed.

Answer (score 2):

Not a core git expert, but here is my hypothesis: When you use the `--tags` flag, all the refs are already stored in memory before the hook is executed. From manpage for git-push:

```
   --tags
       All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.
```

Since the refs are already present in memory, your pre-push hook changing tag names / removing and creating new tags does not have any effect.

IMO, to take care of such cases, you can simply modify your pre-push hook to fail if even one tag is named incorrectly, after changing all the tag names. Afterwards, run the pre-push again.

Alternatively, you can have a custom command - a git alias, which renames all the tags as per your requirements, and than calls `git push --tags`. Check  [How to embed bash script directly inside a git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309430/1860929).

Comment: Failing `git push` and forcing user to push again is a very bad solution.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yup, that is a poor hack. Git alias could solve that for you though.

Comment: Do you suggest to create a custom git command and **teach** all the developers to use it?  It is not a solution at all.  Tag renaming must be fully automatic.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Well you would be teaching them to use a pre-push hook, and also to not use a -f with the git push --tags (because the `-f`   can force override the hook). A simple command like `git pushtag` isn't a big learning curve in comparision, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Most of our developers are working under Windows and using different GUI tools, so `git push` is hardwired and can not be substituted with custom git command.  And I don't want to teach anybody to use git command line, especially if user never used command line during his whole life :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just map to `pre-push` hook on the client side, and do your business renaming local tags here.

Comment: Pre-push hook is being executed on client side, as it should according to git manual.  What mapping are you talking about?

Comment: Just rename tags on that hook before they get a chance to be pushed.

Comment: This is what I did exactly.  I renamed tags on that hook.