# How to use a line of hyphen to separate git command results within git alias in git-bash

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I've already created a alias called info to display status, branch and log in git-bash. However, all the information was bunched up and somewhat annoying to read, so i wanted to make it easier on myself when reading it by adding a line of hyphens with new line above and below it. After trying many times, I can't get it to work. Therefore i'm seeking help here.

Here's what I tried before, trying to get one to work before copying it in between git branch and git log.

```
$ git config --global alias.info '!git status && echo && !printf -- '-%.0s' {1..80}; echo "" && echo && git branch && git log'
```

Below is what the result should look like.

```
git status result

-----------------------

git branch result

-----------------------

git log result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ! syntax doe not give the expected result, try and [embed your commands in a shell function within your Git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14994923/6309):

```
alias.info !f() { echo begin arg=$1/$2/end; }; f
```

Or even in a separate script:

```
git config --global alias.info '!sh info.sh'
```

The point is: if you can make it work in a regular shell script, you will be able to call it from an alias.

Or you can even name your script `git-info` (executable, no extension), and simply type:

```
git info
```

No alias needed there: any `git-xxx` script can be called as `git xxx` (if `git-xxx` is in your `PATH`)