# git-difftool: full file tree compare using meld?

Tags: git, meld, difftool

Is there an easy way to compare the file tree of an old git commit with the working file tree, in meld?

git-difftool does something very similar, but I don't want it to actually do any diffing; the whole point is that the tool it is calling can provide a better interface for that.

Comment: see  also [more general version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial) of this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tested this on a recent version of meld and it is now built in.  You can use it with meld <directory path> so "meld ." works for the current directory.  You can checkout a version git co [version]  then git reset [version]^ and then run "meld ." to compare any version with it's previous version.

Answer (score 46):

With `git > 1.7.11`, the `git difftool` command now supports diffing complete directories using the `--dir-diff` command. This can be used together with `meld`:

```
$ git difftool --tool=meld --dir-diff [commit-to-diff-against]
```

Answer (score 6):

I also found this issue annoying so I've made git meld which allows a more comfortable way of diffing arbitrary commits against the working tree or the staging area.  You can find it at https://github.com/wmanley/git-meld .

Comment: What's the difference between git-meld and https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall? I tried both and had the impression the functionality is identical.

Comment: @kynan: Doesn't git-meld let you use meld's directory diff UI to view the changes in a commit, whereas git-diffall would open all diffs (in the diff UI)?

Comment: @pydave afaics both check out the trees of the 2 revisions to diff to temporary directories and then launch a directory diff on those - no difference there.

Comment: @kynan: You're right, I was confused with this git-diffall: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291578/79125