# git tool comparable to bzr qlog

Tags: git, bazaar

For the purpose of code review I got quite used to using the `bzr qlog` command to visually review the changes between two commits. I am now starting to use git and am looking for the equivalent. The three primary features I want are:

- visual selection of the two revisions (like from a standard revision viewer showing the commit name, message, date, branch, etc.)
- viewing changes side-by-side visually
- viewing all the files changed at once, not just one at a time

The closest git combination I've found so far is to register `meld` as the git diff tool and then use `git cola` to compare revisions. Unfortunately the revision viewer here is limited and I can only compare one file at a time.

My fallback solution is of course to use `bzr-git` and then simply run `bzr qlog`. I've tried this and it seems to work alright, I'm just concerned that the moment I start using git-specific features in the repository it will start failing me.

So, is there a git tool, or series of tools, which I can get the same basic result without too much effort?

*NOTE: I'm not interested in commercial solutions like SmartGit*

Comment: A bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459084/git-difftool-full-file-tree-compare-using-meld, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304797/6309 and its GitHub diffall project: https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall

Comment: diffall seems okay, but I need a convenient way to select the revisions to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `gitk`? It should be bundled with git by default. Just run `gitk` from your console. It just doesn't compare revisions side by side, but in diff format (+, -,...).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I really want the side-by-side format as I find it the easiest to visually compare.  Also, I didn't find a way to select two revisions to compare in gitk, it just seems like you can select one at a time.

Comment: You can select one at a time, but if you right click on other revision, it gives you option to make a comparison. But I agree it isn't as comfortable as it could be.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a vim user, check out the excellent [vim fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and its Gdiff command.