# git difftool: how to measure progress, that is number of files diff'ed and to diff?

Tags: git, prompt, difftool

I know I can [use `git difftool` with the `--dir-diff` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115188/6309) in order to compare all the files in one go.

But using `difftool` with prompt has its use (for a reasonably small number of files to diff), especially [since git 1.7.8, where you can skip a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403439/6309).

However, that prompt doesn't show how many files are in the diff queue or how many has already been diff'ed.
How would you display that information in the `difftool` prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git alone, you can't (git 1.8.x).
But that feature is coming (in Git 1.9/2.0 Q1 2014)

See [commit 6904f9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6904f9aa5ba7666cdb5390733225e123fe25526b) from [Zoltan Klinger](https://github.com/zklinger)'s [patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg221542.html).

> When `--prompt` option is set, `git-difftool` displays a prompt for each modified file to be viewed in an external diff program. At that point it could be useful to display a counter and the total number of files in the diff queue.
>
> Below is the current difftool prompt for the first of 5 modified files:

```
Viewing: 'diff.c'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]:
```

> Consider the modified prompt:

```
Viewing (1/5): 'diff.c'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]:
```

> The current `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` mechanism does not tell the number of paths in the diff queue nor the current counter.
>   To make this "`counter/total`" info available for `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` programs without
>   breaking existing ones:
>
> 1. Modify [`run_external_diff()` function](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6904f9aa5ba7666cdb5390733225e123fe25526b#diff-ab603fc6eadf618560316097522fe585R2899) in [`diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6904f9aa5ba7666cdb5390733225e123fe25526b/diff.c) to set one environment variable for a counter and one for the total number of files in the diff queue.
>      The size of the diff queue is already available in the `diff_queue_struct`.
>      For the counter define a new variable in the `diff_options` struct and reset it to zero in `diff_setup_done()` function.
>      Pre-increment the counter inside the `run_external_diff()` function.
> 2. Modify [`git-difftool--helper.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6904f9aa5ba7666cdb5390733225e123fe25526b/git-difftool--helper.sh) script to [display the counter and the diff
>      queue count values](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6904f9aa5ba7666cdb5390733225e123fe25526b#diff-392c1c67a92baca970520430bb91fdd8L40) in the `difftool` prompt.

That results in:

```sh
git-difftool--helper.sh @@ launch_merge_tool () {

 # the user with the real $MERGED name before launching $merge_tool.
 if should_prompt
 then
   printf "\nViewing (%s/%s): '%s'\n" "$GIT_DIFF_PATH_COUNTER" \
     "$GIT_DIFF_PATH_TOTAL" "$MERGED"
 if use_ext_cmd
 then
   printf "Launch '%s' [Y/n]: " \
```

Comment: Nice to know. Q4 is still a long way to go though. In any case, here's your [Sock Puppet](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet) ;-)

Comment: @janos Oops, I meant Q1 2014, not Q4. And thanks for the hat!