# How can I get a side-by-side diff when I do "git diff"?

Tags: git, git-diff, code-visualization

When I type `git diff`, I'd like to see a side-by-side diff, like with `diff -y`, or like to display the diff in an interactive diff tool like `kdiff3`. How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view 'git diff' output with visual diff program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program)

Comment: Note: you have a [side-by-side diff on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25657797/6309).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I view 'git diff' output with my preferred diff tool/ viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer)

Comment: Damn, this is annoying that you can't do it like with `diff`. I better get used to reading the non-side-by-side format, which is hard for a visual person.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Although Git has an internal implementation of diff, you can set up an external tool instead.

There are two different ways to specify an external diff tool:

1. setting the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` and the `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` environment variables.
2. configuring the external diff tool via `git config`

`ymattw`'s answer is also pretty neat, using `ydiff`

See also:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration
- `git diff --help`
- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/diffs/

When doing a `git diff`, Git checks both the settings of above environment variables and its `.gitconfig` file.

By default, Git passes the following seven arguments to the diff program:

```
path  old-file  old-hex old-mode  new-file  new-hex new-mode
```

You typically only need the old-file and new-file parameters. Of course most diff tools only take two file names as an argument. This means that you need to write a small wrapper-script, which takes the arguments which Git provides to the script, and hands them on to the external git program of your choice.

Let's say you put your wrapper-script under `~/scripts/my_diff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# un-comment one diff tool you'd like to use

# use standard diff command with options: (2023)
/usr/bin/diff -y "$2" "$5" 

# side-by-side diff with custom options:
# /usr/bin/sdiff -w200 -l "$2" "$5" 

# using kdiff3 as the side-by-side diff:
# /usr/bin/kdiff3 "$2" "$5"

# using Meld 
/usr/bin/meld "$2" "$5"

# using VIM
# /usr/bin/vim -d "$2" "$5"
```

you then need to make that script executable:

```
chmod a+x ~/scripts/my_diff.sh
```

you then need to tell Git how and where to find your custom diff wrapper script.
You have three choices how to do that: (I prefer editing the .gitconfig file)

1. Using `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`, `GIT_DIFF_OPTS`

   e.g. in your .bashrc or .bash_profile file you can set:

   ```
    GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=$HOME/scripts/my_diff.sh
    export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
   ```
2. Using `git config`

   use "git config" to define where your wrapper script can be found:

   ```
    git config --global diff.external ~/scripts/my_diff.sh
   ```
3. Editing your `~/.gitconfig` file

   you can edit your `~/.gitconfig` file to add these lines:

   ```
    [diff]
      external = ~/scripts/my_diff.sh
   ```

Note:

Similarly to installing your custom diff tool, you can also install a custom merge-tool, which could be a visual merging tool to better help visualizing the merge. (see the progit.org page)

See: http://fredpalma.com/518/visual-diff-and-merge-tool/ and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Does this retain git terminal coloring?

Comment: This is great, but it launches a new viewer for every file. Any way to create a consolidated diff in, say, `meld`?

Comment: @Tilo I am getting error for vim as im: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

Comment: Can the `meld` version be configured to do a directory diff, where I can choose which file(s) I want to see the diff for? Currently it runs a separate `meld` command for each file, and I have to quit `meld` in order to see the next file. I'd rather have `meld` show me a directory listing of changed files like it behaves when `meld` is used from Mercurial.

Comment: I don't want to vote this answer down. But the answer from ymattw was very easy to implement.

Answer (score 269):

## Try git difftool

Use [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) instead of [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). You'll never go back.

#### UPDATE to add an example usage:

Here is a link to another stackoverflow that talks about `git difftool`:  [How do I view 'git diff' output with my preferred diff tool/ viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program)

For newer versions of `git`, the `difftool` command supports many external diff tools out-of-the-box. For example `vimdiff` is auto supported and can be opened from the command line by:

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
git difftool --tool=vimdiff
```

Other supported external diff tools are listed via `git difftool --tool-help` here is an example output:

```
'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
        araxis
        kompare
        vimdiff
        vimdiff2

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
        bc3
        codecompare
        deltawalker
        diffuse
        ecmerge
        emerge
        gvimdiff
        gvimdiff2
        kdiff3
        meld
        opendiff
        tkdiff
        xxdiff
```

Comment: Or maybe you will go back if you get `This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.`. Perhaps update answer with minimal how-to configure this thing, so that it display side-by-side diffs in terminal, which is what OP asked for? GUI tools are quite useless on remote server where you connect using ssh.

Comment: Interesting point, though I don't think I've personally ever needed to use git while SSH'd. Once of the nice things about DVCS is the Distributed part: at least in my environments it's never a hassle to locally clone whatever repo I want to poke around.

Comment: At least in my config, `git difftool` with `vimdiff` doesn't always line up the two files/buffers correctly.

Comment: Thats nice, and so down below in the answer list :O
I use `git difftool -y` to prevent tkdiff prompt

Comment: Related: make meld your `git difftool` in Windows & Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48979939/4561887

Comment: We need command line diffing for other reasons, like over plaintext chat when collaborating (e.g. a code review) or when doing something over ssh.

Comment: Related: open all differences at once instead of serially by using `dir-diff` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746292/1518546

Comment: Just a heads-up that the list of Available tools seems to be based on certain app names being in `$PATH`. "Araxis" is a tool for Windows and Mac whose name in the shell is `compare`. `compare` also happens to be a program included with ImageMagick on Linux, so if you've never heard of Araxis and see it on your machine you probably don't actually have it and passing it to `--tool=` will do nothing.

Answer (score 98):

You can also try `git diff --word-diff`.
It's not exactly side-by-side, but somehow better, so you might prefer it to your actual side-by-side need.

Comment: This is the easiest way. What's even better is `git diff --word-diff=color`

Comment: @Rolf `--word-diff=color` gives me an invalid option error. Which version was it introduced in?

Comment: @Trengot I run git 1.7.9 which is from 02/2012

Comment: @Rolf default installed version here is 1.7.1. Could explain the difference. `git diff --color-words` does work.

Comment: Yes, `git diff --color-words` is the way to go on modern git versions.

Comment: Somehow better, not very poetic, but accurate!

Answer (score 60):

**`ydiff`**

Formerly called `cdiff`, this tool can display **side by side**, **incremental**, and **colorful** diff.

Instead of doing `git diff`, do:

```
ydiff -s -w0
```

This will launch `ydiff` in side-by-side display mode for each of the files with differences.

Install with:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ydiff
```

-or-

```
brew install ydiff
```

For `git log`, you can use:

```
ydiff -ls -w0
```

`-w0` auto-detects your terminal width.  See the `ydiff` [GitHub repository page](https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff) for detail and demo.

Tested in Git 2.18.0, ydiff 1.1.

Comment: @RyneEverett: Can you explain how to do the equivalent of `git diff | cdiff -s` with icdiff?

Comment: Just run `ydiff -s` from a git/svn/hg workspace, you don't have to pipe in.

Comment: if you want to limit the diff to a specific file through Git's history, `cd <git repo>` and then run `ydiff -ls <path/to/file>`

Comment: I installed it with pip, but still I the the command ydiff on the console not found, because it is intalled as `~/.local/bin/ydiff`

Comment: the `ydiff` does not work for me

Answer (score 34):

You can do a side-by-side `diff` using `sdiff` as follows:

```
$ git difftool -y -x sdiff  HEAD^ | less
```

where `HEAD^` is an example that you should replace with whatever you want to diff against.

I found this solution [here](https://coderwall.com/p/pa5whg/git-side-by-side-diff-in-terminal) where there are a couple of other suggestions also. However, this one answer's the OP's question succinctly and clearly.

See the [man git-difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) for an explanation of the arguments.

---

Taking the comments on board, you can create a handy `git sdiff` command by writing the following executable script:

```
#!/bin/sh
git difftool -y -x "sdiff -w $(tput cols)" "${@}" | less
```

Save it as `/usr/bin/git-sdiff` and `chmod +x` it. Then you'll be able to do this:

```
$ git sdiff HEAD^
```

#### Extra Tip

As suggested in comments you can use `icdiff` to do what `sdiff` does with colored output:

```
$ more /usr/bin/git-sdiff
#!/bin/sh
git difftool -y -x "icdiff --cols $(tput cols)" "${@}" | less --raw-control-chars
```

Answer (score 15):

For unix, combining just `git` and the built-in `diff`:

```
git show HEAD:path/to/file | diff -y - path/to/file
```

Of course, you can replace HEAD with any other git reference, and you probably want to add something like `-W 170` to the diff command.

This assumes that you are just comparing your directory contents with a past commit. Comparing between two commits is more complex. If your shell is `bash` you can use "process substitution":

```
diff -y -W 170 <(git show REF1:path/to/file) <(git show REF2:path/to/file)
```

where `REF1` and `REF2` are git references – tags, branches or hashes.

Comment: Thanks -- your command 'git show HEAD:path/to/file' was what I needed to come up with my own solution, 'vimdfiff <(git show HEAD:path/to/file) path/to/file'. The bits still aren't lined up correctly, but that's the best solution I've got right now.

Answer (score 14):

I recently implemented a tool that does exactly this: https://github.com/banga/git-split-diffs

Here's how to use it:

```
npm install -g git-split-diffs

git config --global core.pager "git-split-diffs --color | less -RFX"
```

And this is how it looks in your terminal (with the default theme):

[image: Preview of side by side diffs]

As you can see, it also supports syntax highlighting and highlighting changed words within lines

Comment: wow. this tool is so great. thanks man for this awesomeness!

Comment: but its a little bit slow, takes 2 seconds to load just a file

Comment: There are some notes on performance at https://github.com/banga/git-split-diffs#performance, but if this seems different, it would be great if you could file an issue. Thanks!

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you! Works great when I run `git diff --staged`

Answer (score 9):

```
export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='meld $2 $5; echo >/dev/null'
```

then simply:

```
git diff
```

Comment: `meld .' works too! And it shows all of the changes in a consolidated window.

Comment: @HRJ that works perfectly! So simple and practical :)

Comment: ```meld``` works also quite good with XQartz-X-Display-Redirect. (Debian to macOS)

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to see side-by-side diffs in a browser without involving GitHub, you might enjoy [git webdiff](https://github.com/danvk/webdiff#git-webdiff), a drop-in replacement for `git diff`:

```
$ pip install webdiff
$ git webdiff
```

This offers a number of advantages over traditional GUI difftools like `tkdiff` in that it can give you syntax highlighting and show image diffs.

Read more about it [here](http://www.danvk.org/wp/2014-07-03/introducing-git-webdiff/).

Answer (score 8):

I use [colordiff](http://colordiff.org).

On Mac OS X, install it with

```
$ sudo port install colordiff
```

On Linux is possibly `apt get install colordiff` or something like that, depending on your distro.

Then:

```
$ git difftool --extcmd="colordiff -ydw" HEAD^ HEAD
```

Or create an alias

```
$ git alias diffy "difftool --extcmd=\"colordiff -ydw\""
```

Then you can use it

```
$ git diffy HEAD^ HEAD
```

I called it "diffy" because `diff -y` is the side-by-side diff in unix. Colordiff also adds colors, that are nicer.
In the option `-ydw`, the `y` is for the side-by-side, the `w` is to ignore whitespaces, and the `d` is to produce the minimal diff (usually you get a better result as diff)

Comment: add `-y` to skip the `Launch 'colordiff' [Y/n]:` prompt.

Comment: are you sure it is `git alias diffy "difftool --extcmd=\"colordiff -ydw\""`?  Shouldn't it be `git config --global alias.diffy "difftool --extcmd=\"colordiff -ydw\""` ?

Comment: Please correct to ```apt install colordiff``` or ```apt-get install colordiff```, ```apt get install colordiff``` is not working.

Answer (score 6):

I personally really like [icdiff](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff) !

If you're on `Mac OS X` with `HomeBrew`, just do `brew install icdiff`.

To get the file labels correctly, plus other cool features, I have in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
    difftool = true
[diff]
    tool = icdiff
[difftool "icdiff"]
    cmd = icdiff --head=5000 --highlight --line-numbers -L \"$BASE\" -L \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

And I use it like: `git difftool`

Answer (score 4):

This question showed up when I was searching for a fast way to use git builtin way to locate differences. My solution criteria:

- Fast startup, needed builtin options
- Can handle many formats easily, xml, different programming languages
- Quickly identify small code changes in big textfiles

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git) to get color in git.

To get side by side diff instead of line diff I tweaked [mb14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376113/mb14)'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905870/2235850) on this question with the following parameters:

```
$ git diff --word-diff-regex="[A-Za-z0-9. ]|[^[:space:]]"
```

If you do not like the extra [- or {+ the option `--word-diff=color` can be used.

```
$ git diff --word-diff-regex="[A-Za-z0-9. ]|[^[:space:]]" --word-diff=color
```

That helped to get proper comparison with both json and xml text and java code.

In summary the `--word-diff-regex` options has a helpful visibility together with color settings to get a colorized side by side source code experience compared to the standard line diff, when browsing through big files with small line changes.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`delta`](https://dandavison.github.io/delta/configuration.html).

In your gitconfig file (usually `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config`),

add:

```
[core]
  pager = delta --light --side-by-side
```

Answer (score 3):

Open [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), select a single or multiple commits in the "Version Control" tool window, browse changed files, and double click them to inspect changes side by side for each file.

With the bundled command-line launcher you can bring IDEA up anywhere with a simple `idea some/path`

[image: version control view]
[image: diff view]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach.  If you pipe through less, the xterm width is set to 80, which ain't so hot.  But if you proceed the command with, e.g. COLS=210, you can utilize your expanded xterm.

```
gitdiff()
{
    local width=${COLS:-$(tput cols)}
    GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF="diff -yW$width \$2 \$5; echo >/dev/null" git diff "$@"
}
```

Comment: Funny.  I signed by name with a pseudonym but that was ignored... Thanks for outing me, Stack Overflow.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Several others already mentioned [cdiff](https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff) for git side-by-side diffing but no one gave a full implementation of it.

Setup cdiff:

```
git clone https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff.git
cd cdiff
ln -s `pwd`/cdiff ~/bin/cdiff
hash -r # refresh your PATH executable in bash (or 'rehash' if you use tcsh)
        # or just create a new terminal
```

Edit ~/.gitconfig inserting these lines:

```
[pager]
        diff = false
        show = false

[diff]
        tool = cdiff
        external = "cdiff -s $2 $5 #"

[difftool "cdiff"]
        cmd = cdiff -s \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

[alias]
        showw = show --ext-dif
```

The pager off is needed for cdiff to work with Diff, it is essentially a pager anyway so this is fine. Difftool will work regardless of these settings.

The show alias is needed because git show only supports external diff tools via argument.

The '#' at the end of the diff external command is important. Git's diff command appends a $@ (all available diff variables) to the diff command, but we only want the two filenames. So we call out those two explicitly with $2 and $5, and then hide the $@ behind a comment which would otherwise confuse sdiff. Resulting in an error that looks like:

```
fatal: <FILENAME>: no such path in the working tree
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

Git commands that now produce side-by-side diffing:

```
git diff <SHA1> <SHA2> 
git difftool <SHA1> <SHA2>
git showw <SHA>
```

Cdiff usage:

```
'SPACEBAR' - Advances the page of the current file.
'Q'        - Quits current file, thus advancing you to the next file.
```

You now have side-by-side diff via git diff and difftool. And you have the cdiff python source code for power user customization should you need it.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a somewhat limited solution, but does the job using the system's `diff` command without external tools:

```
diff -y  <(git show from-rev:the/file/path) <(git show to-rev:the/file/path)
```

- filter just the change lines use `--suppress-common-lines` (if your `diff` supports the option).
- no colors in this case, just the usual `diff` markers
- can tweak the column width `--width=term-width`; in Bash can get the width as `$COLUMNS` or `tput cols`.

This can be wrapped into a helper git-script too for more convenience, for example, usage like this:

```
git diffy the/file/path --from rev1 --to rev2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions:

**Solution 1 : Meld :**

Install meld (in ubuntu I used  `sudo apt install meld`). Then configure it like bellow.

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
git config --global difftool.meld.path "$(which meld)"
git config --global difftool.prompt false

git config --global merge.tool meld
git config --global mergetool.meld.path "$(which meld)"
```

**Solution 2 : Delta :**

If you decide to use cli, then install [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta). The config I use is:

```
git config --global core.pager 'delta'
git config --global interactive.diffFilter 'delta --color-only'
git config --global delta.side-by-side true
git config --global delta.line-numbers true
git config --global delta.syntax-theme 'Solarized (dark)'
```

**Solution 3 : Melt :**

You can also use [Melt](https://github.com/jabbalaci/melt). It's syntax highlighting is done with [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat). This is also a cli tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good answers on this thread.  My solution for this issue was to write a script.

Name this 'git-scriptname' (and make it executable and put it in your PATH, like any script), and you can invoke it like a normal git command by running

```
$ git scriptname
```

The actual functionality is just the last line.  Here's the source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
#
#   Show a side-by-side diff of a particular file how it currently exists between:
#       * the file system
#       * in HEAD (latest committed changes)

function usage() {
    cat <<-HERE
    USAGE

    $(basename $1) <file>

    Show a side-by-side diff of a particular file between the current versions:

        * on the file system (latest edited changes)
        * in HEAD (latest committed changes)

HERE
}

if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then
    usage $0
    exit
fi

file=$1
diff -y =(git show HEAD:$file) $file | pygmentize -g | less -R
```