# Viewing git patch without context

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, meld, git-patch

Since apart from the actual changes, each patch contains a little bit of surrounding lines,
I wanted to use that information and present me a side-by-side comparison with nice visual representation edited lines, removed lines and so on - the one we're used to in meld / IDE.
I just hate "pluses-minuses" view.

I know patch is missing whole affected file contents, but 1 or 2 surrounding lines are always present in a patch - that will be sufficient for me.

Does any tool make this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a side-by-side diff when I do "git diff"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff)