# how to store git format-patch data to a variable instead of writing to a file?

Tags: python, git, git-diff, git-patch

how to store `git format-patch` output to a variable instead of writing to a disk using python?

or is there any other way to create a `git diff` with subject line  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--stdout` option to `git format-patch`

the complete Python expression should be like: `var = subprocess.check_output(["git", "format-patch", "--stdout", <tree-ish arguments...>])`

Also you may consider using [GitPython](https://gitorious.org/git-python) if you need extensive git repo manipulations

Comment: is there a way of side-by-side diff generation in patch file ?

Comment: Well, `git diff` allows to run external diff, including side by side diff. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff However likely `git format-patch` doesn't support this. If you manage to get side by side diff with "stock" `git diff`, then you may try to use these flags in `git format-patch` too.