# Colored, side by side, inline git diff output in my terminal

Tags: git, git-diff, sdiff

Please note this question is not a duplicate of, but a followup to the question ["How can I get a side-by-side diff when I do “git diff”?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff).  This question seeks new information and the solution to a problem.

Also, please note that I am seeking only solutions whose output is inline in the terminal like the default `git diff` is -- I don't want anything which opens an external gui diff program.

### Progress so far

I have followed the suggestion from the SO question linked above and put the following executable on my path:

```
#!/bin/bash

# side-by-side diff with custom options:
sdiff -w200 -l "$2" "$5"
```

I can then test it like so, for example:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=mydiff git diff HEAD HEAD~1
```

and I'll get output like this:

[image: Screenshot]

### The Problem

As intended, this is:

- inline in the terminal
- side by side output

However, it has a couple problems:

- If more than one file has changed, it dies after processing the first file, outputting the error `fatal: external diff died, stopping at <filename>`
- The output doesn't use green/red colors to show new code / deletions.

Is there a way to remedy those two issues with `sdiff`?  If not, is there a way to do it with `/usr/bin/diff`, the built in git diff program, or another terminal program?  I don't care how I accomplish the goal.  I just want inline, side by side diffs with color.

Comment: If there is a way to do this from the terminal, it would be really cool.  But as a workaround, do you have access to an IDE like IntelliJ?  IntelliJ has a great diff tool which works well with Git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[THIS]](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/wiki/Git-diff-side-by-side) worked fine for me, even with colors.
(Thanks @ github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach)

If your terminal has issues displaying colors with sdiff, you probably want to pipe **sdiff** to **colordiff** like:

```
sdiff -w200 -l "$2" "$5" | colordiff | grep -E ...
```

Comment: TYVM!  Still have a couple minor issues after setting up icdiff.  1. Per my post, in my `mydiff` bash script I now have `icdiff --unified=2 --line-numbers "$2" "$5"` (the bash wrapper seems required to keep it inline).  This works, however the file names in the icdiff output look weird, eg `/var/folders/r5/tx39k3394y99z55mzn683ypr0000gn/T//iyhopb_authn_ldap.gemspec`.  Also, for more than a screenful of output, I have to press `q` when it finishes to get my prompt back.  Any ideas for fixing those issues?

Comment: Turns out `icdiff --unified=2 --line-numbers -L "$1" -L "$1" "$2" "$5"` solves the naming issue.  And `--no-pager` would solve the `q` issue, but on second thought I don't think I actually want that, and it's default behavior for git-diff anyway