# What is your diff workflow?

Tags: git

When you have a merge conflict, what is your workflow?

Answer (score 1):

For diff purposes, I often use one of the scripts mentioned in the SO question "[git difftool, open all diff files immediately, not in serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial)".

That way, I can see all the files diff'ed at once, avoiding flippping between files.