# git diff with opendiff gives "Couldn't launch FileMerge" error

Tags: xcode, git, filemerge, opendiff

I have git configured to use ~/bin/opendiff-git.sh as my external diff tool. That script looks like this:

```
opendiff $2 $5
```

When I try and do a git diff from the command line, I get this message:

```
2011-02-18 13:58:55.532 opendiff[27959:60f] exception raised trying to run FileMerge: launch path not accessible
2011-02-18 13:58:55.535 opendiff[27959:60f] Couldn't launch FileMerge
external diff died, stopping at source/some_file.m.
```

What's going on? This has worked for many months, but stopped working recently.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So AFTER I deleted the beta developer folder to try and solve this (couldn't get the fix to work with merge tool) I stumbled upon this in the command line:

```
Error: No developer directory found at /Developer Beta. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.
```

Turns out you can set the developer path you need it to use:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version
```

Looks like installing the beta had automatically set that path to beta. To fix it, run this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Developer
```

That fixed it for me.

#### Update

Ying's comment below was important enough to include in the answer. From Xcode 4.3 on, the location of the folder has changed to inside the application package:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: sweet, that worked for me. With 4.3 on Lion, the Developer folder is now in the Xcode bundle itself, hence: sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

Answer (score 2):

If you have two SDKs installed, and the latest (presumably beta) version doesn't have the System Tools installed, some tools like `opendiff` can break. You can only have one set of System Tools installed at a time, so you have to choose which SDK/installation has it. I fixed this problem by using the path of `opendiff` that is in the Developer folder that had the system tools installed.

In my case, I have the following Xcode installations:

**Current stable release (with System Tools installed)**

```
/Developer
```

**Latest beta (without System Tools installed)**

```
/Developer (iOS SDK XXX beta)
```

My `~/bin/opendiff-git.sh` script now looks like this:

```
"/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff" $2 $5
```

Comment: Even after adding that file I still get the error... :( I'm no sure to understand why... Are you sure about the ~/bin/... part ?

Comment: I used this answer here to set it up originally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736911/how-do-you-make-git-diff-use-gitx-diff-on-os-x/1251394#1251394. Only difference is, I put my `opendiff-git.sh` in `~/bin` instead of `~`, which means you also have to set the git `diff.external` global config option to `~/bin/opendiff-git.sh`. You can get rid of the `bin` if your `opendiff-git.sh` script is in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

first the reason is xcode's installation path  modified since 4.3, so must reselect xcode path

full guide is in below link:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/2/17/updating-to-xcode-43.html