# command line merge tools for windows

Tags: windows, git, command-line, merge, conflict

Are there command line merge tools for windows? I'm thinking in terms of tools that can be used in conjunction with other tools (e.g. git, unison) to resolve conflicts.

Actually, it doesn't need to strictly be command-line based, as long as it "cooperate" with other command line tools (as I mentioned, git for example), then it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/command_line.html) is a great diff/merge tool for Windows and Mac, and they also offer a command-line and a .NET API version of their diff/merge engine.

Araxis Merge is the only tool I know of at this time that can compare and merge two files with differing text encoding, e.g. a UTF-8 and an ANSI file side-by-side.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I've used [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and I've heard good things about [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). I'm not sure what command line cooperation you're looking for; I use these tools in conjunction with TortoiseSVN without any problems.

Comment: I have winmerge, I don't know if I can make it work with git though. VonC says you can't.

Comment: KDiff3 is excellent. I use it on Windows, Mac OS X, and of course, Linux. It works the same on all three, so keeps your productivity up if you're used to it and switching around platforms. It will also actually resolve some conflicts for you that Git does not. So Git+KDiff3 == more fully automated rebases/merges, which has to be a good thing, provided you check the result afterward.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with graphical merge tools (like WinMerge) is that Git, for instance, [**waits the *exit code*** (or the validation of the user after the exit of the diff tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool/586002#586002), implying that the user first close the external diff tool.

And a pure command-line diff tool is not very practical to use for merge purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 3 Pro supports command line merges and can handle them both interactively or non-interactively (automerging without a window).  It sets the exit code, so it can be integrated with other tools, and it does handle merging files with different encodings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Git Bash for Windows you probably have Vim and that package includes  `vimdiff`.

If you use MSYS2 or Cygwin you could install `mc` (Midnight Commander) and it includes handy `mcdiff` (press F1 for brief help).