# Custom git diff to ignore some conflicts

Tags: git, merge, diff

I'm starting tests to move from cvs to git, and I have a problem on all my tests.

We maintain a custom copy of FreeBSD sources, so in cvs we do the following when a new FreeBSD version is released:

1. Import new freebsd src as a vendor branch
2. Merge changes on HEAD

I tried to do the same with git, and it worked, but almost all FreeBSD files have a custom Id like this:

`$FreeBSD: release/7.0.0/COPYRIGHT 175036 2008-01-01 09:36:30Z imp $`

These lines always change, and because of the place they are stored in the svn repository (release/7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0), git generates a lot of conflicts that needed to be fixed manually.

I would like to know if there is a way to configure git to just ignore diffs on these lines and use the new one without asking.

I can do it with diff command ignoring those lines, like this:

`diff -q -I'[$]FreeBSD:.*$'`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the "accepted" answer, but did you came up with a script doing what you wanted ? If yes, you could post here for the rest of us to use ;)

Comment: I´m going to test it and post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can avoid conflict during merges because of those changes.

What you can do, though, is a little script able to list all files to be merges, do your `diff -q -I'[$]FreeBSD:.*$'` on each of them, and for those with no differences, do a

```
git checkout --theirs theFreeBSDFile
```

then a resume of the merge will be able to comple the conflicting merge.

The '`git checkout --theirs`' check out stage #3 (theirs) for unmerged paths.

Actually, a [`git mergetool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool) would be perfect for the job: just before a merge involving FreeBSD files, set your mergetool utility to that script, as described in the question [Is it possible for git-merge to ignore line-ending differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences/862920#862920).
If you setup the mergetool config to trust the exit code of that script, any file which does not display any differences except FreeBSD custom lines would be '`git checkout --theirs`' and reportedly "merged", the other would not be merged by the same script.
At the end, if a resume still show conflicting file, reset your merge tool to your favorite difftool, and resolve the remaining conflicting files.