# kdiff3 not available as c:/Program

Tags: git, powershell, mergetool, kdiff3, conemu

I need you help here )

I started use ConEmu powershell with git
and as I was recommended i install Kdiff3 for merge procedure

I install KDiff3-64bit-Setup_0.9.98-2 version
and make changes in ginconfig

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
```

but when i try to merge branches i got this error

The merge tool kdiff3 is not available as 'C:/Program'

```
D:\VS_Projects\TsAgent [master +9 ~9 -6 !4 | +72 ~0 -0 !5 !]> git mergetool
Merging:
TsAgent.Data/EspioProvider.cs
TsAgent/Models/Offers/SaveStatusPostModel.cs
TsAgent/TsAgent.csproj
TsAgent/TsAgent.csproj.user
TsAgent/Web.config
Normal merge conflict for 'TsAgent.Data/EspioProvider.cs':
{local}: modified file
{remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (kdiff3):
The merge tool kdiff3 is not available as 'C:/Program'
```

I tried to reinstall Kdiff
install it in different folder without space like c:/KDiff/kdiff3.exe
try to use quotes in Gitconfig (single ' or double ") use different slashes
\ or /
and still got same problem. I can't find someone with same problem in google ;(
maybe u can help me with that....

Best regards and thx!

Comment: Can you try and remove the double-quotes around the path (any path), as in my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2851439/6309?

Comment: What git distro are you using? Try /C/KDiff/kdiff3.exe without quotas.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested, just a suggestions

Try to escape space in "Program\ Files"

```
path = "C:/Program\ Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
```

Or you can use short names, in most cases that will be

```
path = "C:/Progra~1/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
```

Comment: Thx for replay. I tried to install KDiff3 in new folder without whitespace.. like C:\KDiff\kdiff3.exe and still got same problem. But I will try your idea