# How to resolve conflicts while merging and updating files in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I feel I am approaching this all wrong.

I work as part of team and we use git. Now, when I pull updates from my team there are obviously conflicts from time to time - git seems to insert loads of text in the files which isn't good.

Anyway, is there a decent way to manage these conflicts (I'm on windows).

I used winmerge, but from what I can see, It can only compare 2 directories. It makes resolving conflicts a breeze, but requires me to have 2 states of the source in 2 different locations.

Does anybody know a better way to do this or how to integrate the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a mergetool for Git which gets launced for each conflicting file. This works fine if you only have a small number of conflicts. Some links: [Using Beyond Compare](http://cbilson.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-beyond-compare-as-git-mergetool.html), [discussion about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool), [more general instructions](http://gitguru.com/2009/02/22/integrating-git-with-a-visual-merge-tool)and the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html).

There are some script packages that can be used if you have lots of changes.

Basically what you need to do is to get e.g. Beyond Compare to work in Linux:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle=diff3
git config --global merge.tool=bc3
git config --global mergetool.bc3.cmd=/usr/bin/bcompare $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
git config --global mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
```

You can find info on other tools easily, and Git already has support for several tools.

Comment: This is good too: http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html

Comment: You're mixing up the use of built-in support for BC3 with the generic configuration for any merge tool. *Either* you use `merge.tool=bc3` and, if `bcompare` is not in your `PATH`, also `mergetool.bc3.path=/usr/bin/bcompare` (no command line arguments here). *Or* you use `mergetool.bc3.cmd` (with full path and arguments like in your example) and specify additional settings like `mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related question with answers that might also help you:

[Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool)

I've personally gone for [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html) (free), with the following setup (which works for me, it might not be the 'right' way to do things):

in `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`, I have a file `git-merge.sh` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Passing the following parameters to mergetool:
#  local base remote merge_result

base=$1
alocal=$2
remote=$3
result=$4

if [ -f $base ]
then
    p4merge.exe -dl "$base" "$alocal" "$remote" "$result" 
else
    p4merge.exe -dl "$result" "$alocal" "$remote" "$result" 
fi
```

In `C:\Documents and Settings\me` my `.gitconfig` contains the following section:

```
[merge]    
    keepBackup = false
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = \"c:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
```