# Custom editor option while doing a Diff "Side-by-Side" on gerrits

Tags: android, git, gerrit

While doing a Diff "Side-by-Side" on gerrits to check the changes introduced,is there a way to open the diff on custom editor you want to?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to launch a program on your local computer from the Gerrit web interface.  However you can download the two versions of the file using the links provided in Gerrit and then diff them locally with the program of your choice.

Comment: @that sucks..lets say you want to resolve merge conflicts of a gerrit that has 10 files while cherry-picking onto a different branch...its so difficult..do you guyz have any smart ideas to resolve merge conflicts?

Comment: I'm a little confused - merge conflicts aren't handled in gerrit at all.  They are resolved on the client side.  Gerrit does not currently do any git operations to resolve merge conflicts.  On your local machine, you might try `git mergetool` to pull up the editor of your choice when resolving merge conflicts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.11, Gerrit provides an "edit" icon next to the "download" icon on the revision (right-hand) side of the diff view. Clicking on the icon opens an editor in the browser. Editing and saving the file will create a new patch set.

It still isn't ideal for merging conflicts though.