# Git pull compare auto merge workflow

Tags: git, version-control, merge, diff, araxis

I use a great tool for comparing folders and files called Araxis Merge.  It has saved my butt so many times through my career that I am forever thankful and I use it frequently.  I am aware that Araxis Merge has git integration from the command line but I'd like to see if anybody has any insight on automating this specific workflow.

So that I can easily stay on top of all changes I would like to be able to automatically compare every change that goes into a git repository easily using araxis merge folder compare.  My perfect workflow would be to pull the code and have it pop the compare on every pull automatically to show me what changed, regardless if a merge is required or not.  I don't want to manually merge stuff, I like the auto merge, I would just like a high level preview of every file/folder that changed before it does the merge or pulls in new code over the existing code.

Anybody have any ideas on how to automate something like this?  Of course I could write a folder copying bash script that duplicates the source directory first and launches the folder compare after the pull finishes but I wanted to see if anybody has done something like this before with git and/or araxis merge.

Answer (score -1):

Git has 'git-mergetool' which allows you to specify which tool to use when resolving merge conflicts.

Also see: [Merging with "git mergetool"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool)

Comment: yeah ive already got that set for merging, im looking for a folder comparison launched no matter what merges or not with every pull..