# shell script to resolve/cleanup git conflicts?

Tags: git, shell, git-cherry-pick

Was trying to merge new commits from opensource and faced conflicts.
git introduced "<<<<<<< HEAD" and "=======" 
Thought of checking for any shell script to reduce the burden?

Comment: Hope this piece of code helps...grep -rl "<<<<<<< HEAD" test/ | xargs sed -i "/<<<<<<< HEAD/,/=======/d"
grep -rl ">>>>>>> " test/ | xargs sed -i "/>>>>>>> /d"


optmized version:
cd test
git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u | xargs sed -i "/<<<<<<< HEAD/,/=======/d"
git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u | xargs sed -i "/>>>>>>> /d"

Answer (score 1):

You would reduce the burden through a mergetool, which would present you all the files with conflicts to resolve.

See for instance "[Merging With a GUI](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/)" and "[Merging with “git mergetool”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586002/6309)"

```
git mergetool -t kdiff3
```

[image: http://www.gitguys.com/gitguys/merging/images/kdiff3.png]

That way, the GUI merge tool take care of those merge markers for you.