# How to apply an old commit on Git?

Tags: git, bash, commit

So, I'm trying to apply an old commit by using cherry-pick, but seems more difficult than I thought.

This is what the BASH looks like...

```
--HEAD IS IN THE MASTER BRANCH-
git cherry-pick 6a0c632
error: could not apply 6a0c632...
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths> or "git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I've been using Git for only 2 months and the only commands I've used are the basic ones: add, commit, push, pull...

Comment: You need to clean up the conflict, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool

Comment: Well, you're on the right track so far. You'll have to [resolve the merge conflict](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/) next.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: Fix merge conflicts.

**Step 2**: Add fixed file(s).

```
git add <fixed_file>
```

**Step 3**. Continue the cherry-pick.

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```