# How do I make gvimdiff opened by git mergetool open all files at once in tabs?

Tags: git, tabs, git-merge, vimdiff, mergetool

Normally `git -c merge.tool=gvimdiff mergetool` opens files to be merged on by one, in batch mode:

```
Normal merge conflict for '...':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
4 files to edit
... seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] n
merge of ... failed
Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ? y
Normal merge conflict for '...':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
4 files to edit
modules ... seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] n
merge of modules ... failed
Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ? n
```

How do I make it open all files at one, with tabs (like in `gvim -p file1 file2`) that contain the four pane arrangement for each file to be merged?

Comment: Related for difftool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial

Comment: Related non vimdiff specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585844/merging-with-git-mergetool

Answer (score 0):

`git mergetool` flow is designed to resolve conflicts in one file a time. Hence what you are asking for cannot be done in a clean way. However it is possible to create a custom mergetool, that will accumulate input from `git mergetool` in a single `gvim` window. The hack that this "solution" inevitably has to contain is that it must make the `git mergetool` flow believe that the custom mergetool has successfully merged the file, even though it just has opened the file in gvim. This is necessary so that the `git mergetool` flow proceeds to the next file without asking any questions. As a result, if you exit gvim without making any changes, git will still think that all conflicts have been resolved.

A draft version of such a custom mergetool (that opens files in different gvim windows, rather than in tabs) follows:

**.gitconfig**:

```
[mergetool "mygvimdiff"]
    cmd=/path/to/mygvimdiff "$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
    trustExitCode=true
```

**mygvimdiff**:

```
#!/bin/bash

gvim -d -c "wincmd J" "$@"

# wait till gvim loads the temporary files before
# the git mergetool script deletes them
sleep 1

exit 0
```

**Usage**:

```
git mergetool -t mygvimdiff
```

Comment: Maybe better to fake unsuccessful merge? The mergetool still asks for the next file as far as I experimented.

Comment: @Vi. Then someone must answer mergetool's confirmation to proceed